# Is there any highway, road or something else that covers the Grand Tour?

Tags: europe, road-trips, routes

Recently I read about the [Grand Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour). It seems to be a journey or route that was very popular in late renaissance (17. and 18. century). Since it leads trough countries I wanted to visit again, and covers region I think are interesting, I was wondering if there is any European highway or a signed route or something similar, that covers more or less the typical Grand Tour journey.

Comment: Middle Ages is usually taken as 5th-15th century. The Grand Tour was popular in the 17th-18th C.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So how do you call this time period?

Comment: I'd go with 'late renaissance'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are wealthy, like people of that time who completed the Grand Tour, you may be interested in the offers of [VSOE, Venice Simplon Orient Express](http://www.orient-express.com/web/vsoe/journeys.jsp). Most European great cities are visited: London, Paris, Vienna, Prague, Budapest, Venice, Istanbul...

Answer (score 4):

Your question hasn't been answered yet, so here it is: No. :)

The 'Grand Tour' wasn't a predefined trip, but a generic journey through, typically, western and southern Europe, popularized by the English lower upper classes, traveling overland from England through, typically, Belgium, France, Switzerland and Italy.
Note the connection between the time period, indeed the renaissance, and the focus on countries with a stronger Romance influence.